# Chamunda mantra chanting benefits

Tags: shakti, kali, chamunda

What are the benefits of chanting the Chamunda mantra

**aim hrim klim ....**

whether this can be used as a protector mantra from evil effects or give response to those who do bad things?

Comment: How can you determine whether a mantra has an positive effect? This is impossible to do. There are other factors to take into account.

Comment: Please elaborate...

Comment: @SaMolPP You have to add @(username) to notify you are replying to him. To elaborate on his comment, it is possible that chamunda mantra is useless but it seems it is working because of previous good karma. Similarly, it may actually be working. It is practically impossible to differentiate whether it good karma or mantra taking effect. Hope that clears your doubt.

Comment: @Sashwat yes that is what I meant.

Comment: There are two distinct questions in your question. 1. Benefits of chanting chamunda mantra. 2. Relation between Chamunda and Kali. These are different questions which need different answers. Multiple questions asked in a single question creates confusion and not good for the readers of the site. Please remove the 2nd question relation between Kali and Chamunda. This can be asked as a new question. By doing this, we can get a clear answer. Limit your question to one. It helps the site too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please post your 2nd question as a new question? That helps users.

Comment: This mantra and its benefits are explained in Devi Bhagwatam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mantra is well known as the Nava-varna (nine-letter) mantra of Devi. It is one of the most powerful and widely used mantra.

The [Devi Atharvasirsa Upanishad](http://www.aghori.it/Devi%20Mahatmyam%20eng/DEVI%20ATHARVASHIRSHA.pdf) discusses it and according to which this mantra is a giver of bhoga (worldly pleasure), bliss and also final liberation. That is it bestows the chatur varga phalas.

> She is Satva, Rajas and Tamas. She is Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra. She is
>   Prajapati, Indra and Manu. She is the planets, stars and
>   constellations. She is various measures of Time. She is destroyer of
>   sins, giver of both enjoyment and Moksha, without end, giving victory
>   over distractions of Samsara, pure, worth taking refuge, giver of
>   peace, peace personified, we pray to Her.
>
> viyadīkārasaṃyuktaṃ vītihotrasamanvitam ।
>  ardhendulasitaṃ devyā
>   bījaṃ sarvārthasādhakam ॥18॥
>  evamekākṣaraṃ brahma yatayaḥ
>   śuddhacetasaḥ
>  dhyāyanti paramānandamayā jñānāmburāśayaḥ ॥19॥
>
> Akash means ha, with ī syllable, Agni ra, aṃ is the Bijamantra for the
>   Goddess (so hrīṃ is formed). This mantra is able to satisfy all
>   desires. Those Yogis whose mind is pure, meditate on this one syllable
>   Brahma, they are having extreme happiness and like an ocean of
>   knowledge.
>
> vāṅmāyā brahmasūstasmāt ṣaṣṭhaṃ vaktrasamanvitam suryo
>   ̕vāmaśrotrabindusaṃyuktaṣṭāttṛtīyakaḥ ।
>  nārāyaṇena saṃmiśro
>   vāyuścādharayuk tataḥ vicce
>  navārṇako ̕rṇaḥ syānmahadānandadāyakaḥ
>   ॥20॥
>
> Vak aiṃ, Maya hrīṃ, Brahma or Kama klīṃ, the sixth consonant ca with
>   Vaktra ā, Surya ma, the right ear u, and Bindu aṃ, the third from ṭ
>   (ḍ), with Narayana ā, Vayu ya, with lips ai and at the end vicce (so
>   aiṃ hrīṃ klīṃ chamunḍāye vicce is formed). **This navarna
>   (nine-lettered) mantra gives pleasure, bliss, and nearness the
>   meditator to Brahman.**

Comment: While appreciating your knowledge in Saakteya traditions, I would like to mention that your answer did not provide reply to the 2nd question of the OP - "whether this can be used as a protector mantra from evil effects or give response to those who do bad things?" @Rickross

Comment: Dhanyosmi,......  me, just a kid,  trying to understand various deities, various mantras available in shaktism.... may be this is a journey where there is no destination !!

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Yes I know but you can write partial answers .. it is definitely a protective mantra because it is related to Chamunda or Durga who herself is the slayer of evil but right now I am not having the needed reference

Comment: No problem .. Ok let's hope so :) @SaMolPP

Comment: In one of my other questions,  devi rakthachamundi was mentioned. Yesterday i went to a guru, asked this,  the response was,  its one of the flavours of Kaali Ma. Its facilitated as "theyyam" in kerala ( northern part of kerala, malabar region ). Its regarded  as one of the samhaaramurthis !! Similarly "Rakteswari ",  as well...

Comment: Ok I am aware of that question .. will have to check some texts to know whether I am able to answer it or not @SaMolPP

Comment: Does this mantra has to be chanted with adding namaha at the end or just vichche @Rickross

Comment: No namaha .. it ends with Vicche only @Santhosh

Answer (score 4):

As **@Rickross** provided answer to 1 question, I am providing answer to the 2nd question -  "**whether this can be used as a protector mantra from evil effects or give response to those who do bad things**?".

The following is an excerpt from 12th Chapter of Devi Maahatmyam or Durga Saptasathi, which contains the **chAmunda mantra**.

> http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/markandeyapurana34.html
>
> Those who read or hear the eulogies about Maha Devi, particularly on Ashtami, Navami or Chaturdashi days would qualify human beings for diminishing sins, removal of poverty, as ***also safe-guarding against enemies, robbers, fire and water hazards, weapons, diseases, family unrest and general discontentment***.

Sanskrit text of 12th Chapter of Devi Maahatmyam or Durga Saptasathi can be viewed at Page 88 (5 and 6 slokas) can be viewed at the following link.

https://sanskrit.safire.com/pdf/DURGA700color.pdf